# Android app zero devices supported on playstore

Tags: android, android-manifest

When I upload my app on playstore, google playstore give me "Zero devices supported".

I have followed all guidelines of android developer before uploading app.
I want publish my app only for phone.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.schoolgame"
android:versionCode="22"
android:versionName="3.1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
  />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EnglishHomeActivity"
        android:label="Home"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="Sign up"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send_info"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".ItalianHomeActivity"
        android:label="Home"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateEmailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_email"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_info"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdatePasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_password"
        android:theme="@style/SchoolGameTheme" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'){
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.schoolgame"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 22
    versionName "3.1"
}
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: remove <compatible-screens> </compatible-screens> tag and submit apk

Answer (score 1):

Do not use  `<compatible-screens>`  tag  as adviced in [developer_guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

instead use  tag.
For example:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Since you don't want to support tablets you should exclude
    android:xlargeScreens="true"

For more information on  visit [developer_support_screen_guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: @DarioLitardi  try removing the common-codecs maven dependency and ad it as per the below comment. We recently faced this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the common-codecs dependency.

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
```

The APK executed fine during internal testing but when published to Playstore , it was showing common-codecs as as a native library and the supported devices to be zero.

The fix was including a local .jar for it in the libs folder and compile using:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```